# Referencing Tilemap inside Grid Prefab

Tags: unity, c#, prefabs

I have a prefab of a grid which contains 3 different tilemaps:

Main, Foreground, & Background

I want to reference the tilemaps inside a script of the prefab but can't figure out how to do that... I just need to edit the tiles in the tilemaps located inside the prefab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Rather than pre-creating the tilemaps inside of the prefab,  You just have to add the tilemaps after the prefab was created (in the game).

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044398/how-to-programmatically-add-tilemaps-to-a-grid

You can add the 3 tilemaps to the grid in the awake function and use their variables:

```
    GameObject go = new GameObject("Main");
    mainTileMap = go.AddComponent<Tilemap>();
    TilemapRenderer tileRenderer = go.AddComponent<TilemapRenderer>();

    mainTileMap.tileAnchor = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    go.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    tileRenderer.sortingLayerName = "Default";
```

and do this for every tilemap. The 'mainTileMap' GameObject will store the reference to the tilemap.

Comment: You do not have to create the tilemaps at runtime for this to work.